# Easiest Method of editing animation curves

Tags: animation, graph-editor

I working to learn to be at least a basic, competent animator in Blender, but have never been much of an animator in any app up to this point. I'm having a hard time editing the animation curves without everything wacking out.

Way back in my early days of 3D, I used one of oldest animation packages, Electric Image.  At the time I used it, it was by far the fastest renderer, although that quickly changed. Even though it was primitive by most standards, there was one thing about it, I wish more apps replicated. It had a separate velocity curve in the curve editor. Using that, you could set up a movement path along XYZ, then tweak the position along that path during the animation using the velocity curve. This allowed you to handle the speed through the animation, without altering the XYZ curves at all.

Is there any way to replicate that sort of behavior in Blender? Besides actually using a spline path, that is. I mainly want to animate figures, not cars or spaceships.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have an existing (keyframed) animation, you can go into the Dopesheet and either speed up or slow down the action or velocity between keyframes by scaling, (expand or compress) the distance between them.  Highlite/select the first to last keyframe you want to vary, place your timeline cursor at the leftmost selected and press S. Move the mouse left or right to see the distance between KF's change.  This varies the number of frames (time available) for the action to take place between one KF and the next.  Use key 'B' to box select a group of frames and/or channels.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/220578/is-there-an-evaluation-time-speed-graph-for-regular-xyz-location-rotation-prope/220604#220604

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That may be the closest I can get to the kind of control I'm looking for.  Probably, I just need to get a lot more practice editing curves in Blender, and get a lot better at it.